# Many to many relationship returns 0 element collection using entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a probably simple question, I am trying to create many to many relationships using entity framework and fluent api, and my problem is that when i try to do any query or view a object in debug it has always 0 items.

I am using junction table that looks like:

[image]

So relations exists, to be sure ive checked:

select candidate.firstname, skillset.name
from candidate 
join candidate_skillset on candidate.id = candidate_skillset.candidate_id
join skillset on candidate_skillset.skillset_id = skillset.id

and joined results are displayed.

Now my context looks like:

```
public class CatalogContexct : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().HasMany(t => t.SkillSets).WithMany(t => t.Candidates)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("candidate_skillset");
            m.MapLeftKey("candidate_id");
            m.MapRightKey("skillset_id");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SkillSet>().ToTable("skillset");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().ToTable("candidate");
    }
}
```

My left side model candidates:

```
[Table("candidate")]
public class Candidate
{
    public Candidate()
    {
        this.SkillSets = new HashSet<SkillSet>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public int? commendation_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("commendation_id")]
    public Commendation commendation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }
}
```

And my rightside model skillset:

```
[Table("skillset")]
public class SkillSet : SimpleDictionary
{
    public SkillSet()
    {
        this.Candidates = new HashSet<Candidate>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
```

and that model has a parent class:

```
public class SimpleDictionary
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So all should work but when I do for example:

```
        var ca = this._catalog.Candidates
            .Include("SkillSets").Include("commendation").
            FirstOrDefault(x => x.SkillSets.Any());
```

Result is null, also when I view object on debug collection of property skillset allays has 0 elements, any idea what could be wrong with it?

Comment: hi did you run sqk server profiler to see what query is getting generated by EF . it will give you some idea what might be wrong .

Comment: Aye I've used entity framework logger to get sql and checked it and Im getting result. So they are not assign to property it seems. Mayby its because Im using sql express??

Comment: please try my answer . I recreated it as per you question details and I was able to get the result .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with same structure mentioned here in you question and tried locally . And I am able to get the data with this code . Please try this and let me know if this helps . I just omitted commendation table for simplicity .

```
        var context = new SampleDbContext();

        var candidates = context.Candidates
            .Include("SkillSets").ToList();


        foreach (var candidate in candidates)
        {
            foreach (var sk in candidate.SkillSets.Where(  s1 => s1.Candidates.Count(c=>c.id == candidate.id)>0 ))
            {
                Console.WriteLine( string.Format(@" Name : {0} Skill :{1}",candidate.Firstname ,sk.Name )  );
            }
        }
```

Below is my DbContext and Other Entity Classes

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SampleDbContext()
            : base("name=SampleDBConnection")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().HasMany(t => t.SkillSets).WithMany(t => t.Candidates)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("candidate_skillset");
            m.MapLeftKey("candidate_id");
            m.MapRightKey("skillset_id");
        });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SkillSet>().ToTable("skillset");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>().ToTable("candidate");
        }
    }

    [Table("candidate")]
    public class Candidate
    {
        public Candidate()
        {
            this.SkillSets = new HashSet<SkillSet>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Column("firstname")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public int? commendation_id { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("commendation_id")]
        //public Commendation commendation { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SkillSet> SkillSets { get; set; }
    }

    public class SimpleDictionary
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("skillset")]
    public class SkillSet : SimpleDictionary
    {
        public SkillSet()
        {
            this.Candidates = new HashSet<Candidate>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    }


}
```

The output of the query you mentioned and the result of my code both matched I hope this is that you wanted .

[image]

Comment: Hmm I tried this creating new project, but using old DB and result is the same, maybe there is some sort of cache to dump in visual studio to refresh this?

Comment: can you please try to do it wil fresh db and enter some values then may be we can look why it is  not happing on old DB

Comment: I hope my answer is satisfactory or helpful  for you . Thanks

Comment: Well it works ok on new db, interesting, ill try to recreate references on old one.

Comment: great :) For old DB can you please check weather all relation ship are correct and the junction table is also correct and filled with correct id

Comment: Basically I have no idea what was the couse, but finally I've duped those tables from old db and created new and it works.